# Too much cayenne chilli pepper

Tags: spices

I have added cayenne chilli pepper, instead of cayenne pepper, and (I think too much) to my green tomato chutney.
How can I reduce the spice and still be able to store the chutney?

Answer (score 1):

There are two traditional ways to reduce the hotness of excess chilli.

First, excessive spicy taste is can be neutralized by adding appropriate filler/absorbent ingredients to the mixture. **Fresh coconut shreds** are commonly used to absorb the excess chilli in chutneys.

Second, you can add sweet and/or sour substances to counter the feeling of hotness. Traditional sour additions to chutney can be:

- Tamarind (common)
- Tomatoes
- Lime or lemon
- Vinegar

Typical sweet alternatives are:

- Honey
- Brown sugar

All these additions may change the flavor and shelf life of the chutney, but you can always experiment. If that is not desirable, just add more of the other recipe ingredients to increase the number of servings.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some oil and letting the capsaicin dissolve in the oil, then pour off the oil.  Of course, you won't get all the oil and many other flavor molecules will dissolve in the oil as well.